# Force right hand rule

Tags: matlab, math, 3d, geometry

Here is what I am trying to do : 

Input : Three 3D {v1,v2,v3} vectors, that are Orthonormal with arbitrary sign.
Output : Two sets of Three 3D {v1s,v2s,v3s} vectors that are Orthonormal and have **specific sign** and that **agree with right-hand-rule**. 

**Assumptions : v1s will have arbitrary sign**.

My question is focused on how to find v2s sign, I would like to force that: v1s and v2s will have signed(!) angle of 90 degrees, same signed angle between v2s,v3s.

About v3s, I plan to calculate in the following way:
v3s = cross(v1s,v2s).

If the question is not defined well, you can define any arbitrary vector as constant.

Comment: The answer doesn't seem to satisfy you, although it's completely right. Can you add a dummy example in your question with 3 input vectors and the expected output? PS : Lutzl in his answer gave you 2 different way of creating your basis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your question is not well defined. In dimensions above 2D, there is no signed angle. You only get a signed angle between two vectors if you fix an orientation on the plane spanned by these vectors, and in general there is no preferred orientation.

In 3D, fixing an orientation amounts to fixing one of the two normalized normal vectors. Thus you can either define `v3` from the unchanged `v1` and `v2` as `v3s = cross(v1s,v2s)` or you fix the unchanged `v3` to define the orientation on the `v1,v2` plane and compute `v2s = cross(v3s,v1s)`.

Comment: LutzL is it possible to define the clock wise order of v1,v2,v3? when v1 will be assumed to be always first.

Comment: I have not the first idea of what that could mean. "clock-wise" seems to imply some 2D projection, and you can always look at that from two sides.